# Strange orientation behavior in Android 7.1.1

Tags: android

Whenever I start an activity that's supposed to be locked in portrait on phones while my phone is in landscape, the activity always starts in landscape for .5s and then moves to portrait. Why is this? Is there a way to make this work normally? My code for this activity is extremely standard, I created a basic application just to test this out.

```
package com.example.ygu.myapplication;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setRequestedOrientation(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTabletStarz) ?     ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE
                : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```